# How to generate txt & xml files in nuxt SSR?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there any way of generating a Google : `ads.txt` file every time i build my **SSR** project?

There is a module called: `sitemap-module` from `nuxt-community`, it is used to generate a `sitemap` xml file, and that file can be accessed by http://domain.tls/sitemap.xml. and i want something like that.

So currently i'am achieving this by building the project, then manually put `ads.txt` it in : `/var/www/site/.nuxt/dist/client/`,

**The problem with this is that everytime i rebuild the project i loose `/var/www/site/.nuxt/dist/client/` folder then i have to add `ads.txt` file again.**

I would like to know how i can hook up my code to tell nuxt to generate `ads.txt` file and put it in `/var/www/site/.nuxt/dist/client/`

---

*Not sure if it makes sense, but i hope someone will understand.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place your ads.txt file in a directory named `static` as mentioned [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/#the-static-directory). All the contents of the static directory can be accessed via `example.com/{filename.extension}`

[image]

If you are not using nuxt.js and just using vue js, place it in a `public` directory right next to `src` directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any way of solving this in `nuxt`, so i decided to redirect all https://domain.tld/ads.txt in Nginx configuration.

*/etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf*

```
#redirect all txt request
location ~* ^.+.(txt)$ {
    root /var/www/other.files/;
}
```

So i think i'll stick to it.